# Перенос строк в javasrcipt

Tags: javascript

Есть строка: 
`var error_text = 'Password does not meet the requirements: \
                    - at least 8 characters. \
                    - at least 1 number. \
                    - at least 1 lowercase character. \
                    - at least 1 uppercase character';`

я передаю эту строку в метод который выводит ошибку напротив поля ввода:

`viewError(password_status, password_tooltip, error_text);`

В методе я задаю текст блоку.

Как сделать перенос строк? Я пробовал `\n` но он не работает.

Comment: если вы хотите перенос в html, то используйте его тэг `<br>`. а вообще, и `\n` должен работать

Comment: У вас в error_text нет переноса строки, заключите текст в такие кавычки: ` , а в html используйте для вашего блока стиль `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Comment: @lexxl `<br>` он выводит просто как текст, без переноса строк.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian я ставил у себя `\n` после точек... но не работает.

Comment: @Tsyklop ну если передавать чистый текст, то да. чтобы работали теги, надо передавать html-код, например метод .innerHTML()   P.S. в вашем примере вместо \n стоит просто слэш, вы точно правильно пробовали использовать \n ?

Comment: @lexxl слешь вместо  `+`. Вот сделал так:

`var error_text = 'Password does not meet the requirements:\n' +
     '- at least 8 characters.\n' +
     '- at least 1 number.\n' +
     '- at least 1 lowercase character.\n' +
     '- at least 1 uppercase character';`

не работает. Я использую JQuery

Comment: Что за блок и с какими он CSS свойствами? Какой код для добавления этого текста Вы используете? Приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример. А то с вашими скупыми данными можно долго гадать на спиритической доске) Просто потому, что с приведенными данными можно обойтись элементарным кодом `<br>`, [ссылка на jsfiidle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcdw6mye/) и в приведенных сведениях никаких причин обратного поведения нет.

Comment: А скорее всего вы используете где-то в недрах секретного для нас метода `viewError`, вместо `$("#element").html(error_text)` метод `$("#element").text(error_text)`, который экранирует все ваши попытки вставить теги.

Comment: @AlexKrass да, именно так и было. Изменил на `html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удалите перенос строк в коде `JS` и используйте `\n`:

```js
var error_text = 'Password does not meet the requirements: \n - at least 8 characters. \n - at least 1 number. \n - at least 1 lowercase character. \n - at least 1 uppercase character';

alert(error_text);
```

Либо используйте `<br>`:

```js
var error_text = 'Password does not meet the requirements: <br>' + 
                 '- at least 8 characters. <br>' +
                 '- at least 1 number. <br>' +
                 '- at least 1 lowercase character. <br>' +
                 '- at least 1 uppercase character';

document.write(error_text);
```

Comment: Я вставил туда тег `<pre>` и сделал добавление не `text` а `html` и всё заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: @Tsyklop, а я удалил свой коммент, думал не поможет :)

Comment: @Tsyklop рад, что ваша проблема решена. отметьте ответ принятым, если он вам помог, нажатием галочки слева от ответа